# What transports should I use for QuestDB ingestion over the ILP protocol?

Tags: questdb, influx-line-protocol

The QuestDB implementation of the InfluxDB Line Protocol client supports two different transports: TCP and HTTP.

What are the differences between these transports? Is there any guidance available on selecting the appropriate protocol for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP transport is recommended for most use cases. It provides feedback on errors, automatically retries failed requests and is easier to configure.

The TCP transport is kept for compatibility with older QuestDB versions. It has limited error feedback, no automatic retries, and requires manual handling of connection failures, even if they are just short network glitches.

TCP transport has a lower overhead than HTTP transport and may be useful in high-throughput scenarios in high-latency networks.